# Xamarin - Webview - OnWebViewNavigating - Redirect to x when original url matches x

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview

I am trying to redirect a url that is coming from a payment provider, for some reason the webview browser doesnt resolve the URL which results in a white screen. When placing the url in a browser the url gets redirected to another url. I thought that i could just redirect the url to the 'correct' url. My problem is that I could not find anything about redirecting  when navigating or how to trigger a new 'Navigating'. Sorry if this is very strait forwards but I am new to xamarin.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webView.Navigating += OnWebViewNavigating;
        webView.Navigated += OnWebViewNavigated;
        
    }

    private void OnWebViewNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.StartsWith("xxxxx"))
        {
            // redirect to correct url
        }
    }

    private void OnWebViewNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Maybe do something here?
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you suggest me to to with the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okee, maybe not a real answer. But my problem is solved. I have build the app to multiple physical devices. And there it works.

Found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168732/call-of-webview-using-xamarin-forms-blank-screen-a

[image]